# How to produce this kind of table?

Tags: tables, overleaf

[image]

I've been trying to produce this kind of table in latex (overleaf) by playing around with \multicolumn, but can never seem to get it right, no matter what I try. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of just posting an image of what you're trying to achieve, show us a small compilable document of what you've tried. This way people can help you faster. But roughly if your table has 8 columns, then `\multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 1} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 2}` should get you your top line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXXXXXX}
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 1} & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Title 2} \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){1-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
    Sub1&Sub2&Sub3&Sub4&Sub1&Sub2&Sub3&Sub4 \\ 
    \midrule
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
 \end{document}
```